# Why extern variable in shared library results in undefined reference only on msvc

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, linker-errors, undefined-reference

Why the following code compiles and runs ok on `clang-10` but got link error on `msvc 19`?

```
// library.h
#pragma once
extern int a;
```

```
// library.cpp
#include "library.h"
int a = 10;
```

```
// test.cpp
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(testlib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

add_library(lib SHARED library.cpp library.h)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE lib)
```

Build target `test` on `Visual Studio 2019` got link error:
`test.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int a" (?a@@3HA)`.

But runs ok on `clang-10` with output `10`.